# Error Resolving User Permissions + Zsh Command Not Found

Tags: path, terminal, permissions, zsh, osx-elcapitan

This is the list of user permissions after logging them to the terminal:

```
➜  ~  ls -ld / /usr /usr/bin /usr/bin/manpath
drwxr-xr-x    33 root  wheel   1190 Nov 14 08:49 /
drwxr-xr-x@   11 root  wheel    374 Nov  7 09:12 /usr
drwxr-xr-x  1055 root  wheel  35870 Nov 12 11:34 /usr/bin
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root  wheel      3 Nov  5 18:13 /usr/bin/manpath -> man
```

And this is the error I receive when trying to update the permissions:

```
➜  ~  chmod 755 / /usr /usr/bin /usr/bin/*
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /usr/bin/apropos: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /usr/bin/at: Operation not permitted
```

This all began as an effort to debug the following zsh error:

```
zsh: command not found
```

I have tried resetting my $PATH variable to no avail. I've uninstalled and reinstalled zsh, run brew doctor, reinstalled node, etc. and am unsure where to proceed from here. The problems I am trying to fix are two-fold:

1. fix the PATH so that I can use commands (e.g.: ionic) from the
   terminal
2. fix the permissions so I don't encounter any further
   errors as I troubleshoot going forward

Can anyone offer guidance? Been trying to debug this for hours.

This my current PATH:

```
➜  ~  echo $PATH                               
echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Comment: Command not found error usually has nothing to do with permissions, because most utilities are world executable. You wrote a wall of text up there, but didn't get to the basic problem: for what command do you get command not found? Without that info we can't possibly help you. Might as well be a syntax error, there's no way to know.

Comment: `➜  ~  ionic start blank
zsh: command not found: ionic`
Apologies for that. I npm installed ionic and cordova and receive the command not found error for both of them.